# Rest API Encountered an Error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl

There is cURL 60: SSL Certificate Issue on my website- https://wiofy.online. I tried installing fresh SSL from SSL for free but it didn't help. What should I do?

Comment: If I inspect your website, there are no issues I can find. What kind of ssl certificate are you using? Is the problem already solved? If not, please tell us some more about how you installed it. The issue seems to be related to expired certificate, but have other reasons too...

Comment: The issue has not been resolved yet. I see two errors- one of them is Rest API and the other one is 'your site could not complete a loopback request'. The SSL certificate is valid till August. I installed SSL form sslforfree.com manually by uploading the verification files in root directory>.wellknown>acme-challenge folder and copying and pasting the keys on the hosting website.